# HttpResponseMessage called twice for content type image/jpeg

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My machine is hosting a RESTful service on MS WebAPI (.net4) and is also connected to a camera. I can make a request to have the camera take a snapshot (jpg) and show the captured image.
Strange thing is, the request is always called 2x - 2 images are captured but only the last image is returned as output. (using google chrome postman to test)

in my server:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(string.Format("http://localhost:{0}/", port));
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SimpleFileHandler());
config.Formatters.Add(new JpegTypeFormatter());
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( /* the route map */
```

in SimpleFileHandler

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

A jpeg content type formatter called JpegMediaFormatter:

```
public class JpegTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    private static Type _supportedType = typeof(MemoryStream);

public JpegTypeFormatter()
{
    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
}

public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
{
    return type == _supportedType;
}

public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
{
    return type == _supportedType;
}
public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private Task GetWriteTask(Stream stream, MemoryStream data)
{
    return new Task(() =>
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(data.ToArray());
            ms.CopyTo(stream);
        });
}

public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        //value = new byte[0];
        value = new MemoryStream();
    }
    Task writeTask = GetWriteTask(writeStream, (MemoryStream)value);
    writeTask.Start();
    return writeTask;
}
```

}

Camera capture RESTful call:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Capture(int width)
{ // call camera API, capture image and save as img
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, memoryStream, 
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
}
```

Somehow calling new MediaTypeHeaderValue() with JPEG content will cause the GET to be called twice.
If I change to call some other MediaType i.e. application/json, the GET is not called 2x.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit: additional details
server code:

```
public Server : IDisposable
{
    HttpSelfHostServer _server;
    public Server()
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:30019");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("capture", "camera/capture/");
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    }
...
}
```

Camera controller:

```
public class CameraController : ApiController
{
    // camera -> variable to camera h/w
    var camera = HW.Camera;
    var img = camera.Capture();
    if(img != null)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            Content = new PushStreamContent((respStream, cnt, ctx) =>
            {
                using(respStream)
                {
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(respStream);
                }
            });
        };
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your requirement...what type is 'img'? and also i think you can avoid creating a custom formatter..example below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Capture(int width)
    { 
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent((responseStream, httpContent, transportContext) =>
            {
                using (responseStream)
                {
                    img.Save(responseStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                }//closing this important!
            });
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

        return response;
    }
```

if you have an image already as a file, then you could just do the following to respond back with an image:

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Capture(int width)
    { 
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Images\Car.jpg"));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: 'img' is just Image object; I removed the custom formatter but still GET is called twice.

Comment: could you share how the code looks like at your client...is it an image tag in html that is making this request for image?

Comment: just a normal GET call i.e. localhost/camera/capture with no content-type

Comment: that is really weird...never heard of this problem...if you could share a repro, i could probably dig deeper into it...currently with the above code, there isn't much that i am able to guess actually